# TypeError: Cannot read property 'upvote' of undefined in mean stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I am using MEAN stack for my application and I have an upvote section in my app for each question, trying to upvote a question says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'upvote' of undefined`. My routes file goes like this:

routes.js

```
app.put('/api/questions/:id/upvote', questions.upvoteQuestion);
```

Question.js (Model)

```
var questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    question: {type:String, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
    category: [String],
    upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
    author: String
});

questionSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
    this.upvotes += 1;
    this.save(cb);
};
```

questions.js (Controller)

```
exports.upvoteQuestion = function(req, res, next) {
    req.question.upvote(function(err, question){
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        res.json(question);
    });
};
```

Not quite sure what the mistake is.

Comment: I do know nothing about the MAN stack but I  know angular, express and nodejs. And javascript of cause ;-) The error message tells you, that req.question is null or undefined. I do not know mongoose enough to be 100'% sure. But I assume that the mongoose middleware does not correctly add the question object to the request. Is there an error log? Or you have forgotten to add the mongoose middleware ;-) Or mongoose uses another variable req.xyz ?

Comment: Where is `req.question` set?

Comment: @mscdex He uses mongose middleware. I assume that this middleware reads an object from the mongodb identified by the :id he provides with app.put(... . Then this object is enriched with the methods defined in questionSchema.methods add added to the request. That can be proven by performing a console.dir(req); as the first line in the function exports.upvoteQuestion

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to refer to upvotes as a property of question, if you change question to this:

```
question: {type:String, required:'{PATH} is required!', upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0}}
```

you can refer to it with this:
    req.question.upvote

and then change the second line of the upvote method to this:

```
questionSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
    this.question.upvotes += 1;
    this.save(cb);
};
```

As it's defined now, upvotes is a property of questionSchema, if that's what you're aiming for you can't refer to it as a property of question.

I haven't worked with mongoose, though.